# How to get multiple options in drop box when I choose a option from first drop box in HTML

Tags: html

HERE If I select Moduelone from the first drop box it should show Tables1's all dropdown options and 
If i select Modueltwo from the first drop box it should show Tables2's all dropdown options

** kindly suggest in Jscript as well as ?php.

```html
  <select id=" File1 " name=" File1">
    <option value="Moduelone">Moduelone</option>
    <option value="Modueltwo">Modueltwo</option>
  </select>
  <select id="Tables1" name="Tables1">
    <option value="Column1">Column1</option>
    <option value="Column2">Column2</option>
    <option value="Column3">Column3</option>
  </select>
  <select id="File2" name="File2">
    <option value="Moduelone">Moduelone</option>
    <option value="Modueltwo">Modueltwo</option>
  </select>
  <select id="Tables2" name="Tables2">
    <option value="Column4">Column4</option>
    <option value="Column5">Column5</option>
    <option value="Column6">Column6</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it with the efforts you made

Comment: So you want to show and hide something based on a condition? 
if(getElementbyId('File1 ').value == "Moduelone") { 
your logic in here }
I dont see any code trying that...